# Ignoring created_at timestamp when working with a Datetime field object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ticketing app built using Rails 4.1, there are two datetime fields (booking_start_date and booking_end_date). I use the following code to ensure that availability of tickets and update the status:

```
def check_start_date
    if(self.booking_start_date >= DateTime.now && DateTime.now < self.booking_end_date)
        if(self.ticket_quantity.to_i > 0) then  
          self.status = 'Open'
        else
          self.status = 'Sold Out'
        end
    elsif(DateTime.now < self.booking_start_date)
        self.status = 'Booking Available soon'

    elsif(DateTime.now >= self.booking_end_date)
        self.status = 'Closed'
    end
end
```

Often it takes a few minutes for the user to fill up the ticket creation form. So, if a user starts at 10.30 AM (which is auto populated in the booking_start_date field) and takes till 10.35 to create the form, the status of the ticket stays empty. Simply put, as long as the booking_start_date is atleast a minute ahead of the created_at date, the status gets updated. How do I ensure that this scenario is taken into account as well?

Comment: So your question is, you want to know how to account for the scenario - 'as long as the booking_start_date is atleast a minute ahead of the created_at date, the status gets updated'. Is that correct?

Comment: @TomKadwill yes, it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add some logic to run when booking_start_date is atleast a minute ahead of the created_at date then you could add another elsif and write something like:

```
elsif(self.created_at + 1.days < self.booking_end_date)
  # your logic
```

I hope that answers your question, if not leave a comment and I'll update the answer.

Comment: is the usage of + correct? I'm getting 'undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass' error.

Comment: Have you saved the record? Stuff like `id` and `created_at` are only set once the record has been saved. The `+` operator will work fine as long as `created_at` is set.

Comment: this is a before_save method, so I guess it isn't.

Comment: You could always add a `started_at` field and set the time when the user makes a new instance. You could use that field instead of `created_at`.

Comment: I'm thinking of using your suggestion in an after_create method, what do you think?

Comment: Ah yes, if you can use an after_create then that is definitely the best approach